# SQL equivalent of pyspark query

Tags: sql, pyspark

Let's assume I have this table

```
user | variable
1    |  2
1    |  3
2    |  4
```

and I have the following pyspark query

```
df.groupby("user").agg(F.udf(lambda x: 2 in x)(F.collect_list("variable")))
```

do you know what's the equivalent of this in SQL?

Comment: What does the pyspark code do/return?

Comment: If you explain the desired results it should be easy to provide an equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pyspark is just checking whether or not a user has a row with `variable==2`...

```
SELECT
  user,
  MAX(CASE WHEN variable = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  user
```

More directly, assuming HiveQL...

```
SELECT
  user,
  array_contains(collect_list(variable), 2)
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  user
```